# Unix- File Editing-Saving

Tags: file, unix, save

I am working on my assignment and these are the instructions. I thought I was almost done but I keep getting an error saying that I did not change anything in the file or did not save it. Not really looking for a solution to whole question but instead a guide to my problem. Any help is appreciated.

```
  Create a new directory, ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst.

    Copy into that directory the file ~cs252/Assignments/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt

    Use one of the three editors discussed in this language to edit the file ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt

    In line 597, change the semicolon (;) to a period, and capitalize the first letter of the word immediately after it.

    Somewhere within that file is the string “man men”. Change it to “many men”.

    Replace all occurrences in the file of the word “elephant” by the word “wombat” (replacing the case variant “Elephant” by “Wombat”).

    Save your changed file, and exit the editor. (Do not rename the file when you save it. It should still be named mtswe10.txt.)

    Use the diff and grep commands to check your changes and make sure that you have made all the changes that you were supposed to and no others.

    Give the command

    ~cs252/bin/editingAsst
```

And here is my solution:

```
mkdir ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst
cp ~cs252/Assignments/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst
sed -i '597 s/\([;]\)/./' ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt
sed -i '' '597 s/(\. [a-z])/\U&\E/' ~/UnixCourse/editingAss/mtswe10.txt
sed -i '' ' s/man men/many men/' ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt
sed -i '' ' s/Elephant/Wombat/g' ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt
sed -i '' ' s/elephant/wombat/g' ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt
```

.

So I am not getting any errors until last step and when I try to save the assignment it gives the error. Also with `sed -i '' '334 s/(\. [a-z])/\U&\E/' ~/UnixCourse/editingAss/mtswe10.txt` is giving a warning but it does accept though.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, I believe, is the extra `''` parameters that you have on all but the first `sed` command.  `sed` treats the first lone parameter as a script, and the second lone parameter as a filename.  So, the second command has an empty script, and a complicated filename that it couldn't handle.  If you get rid of those extra parameters, it should work.

```
mkdir ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst
cp ~cs252/Assignments/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst
sed -i '597 s/\([;]\)/./' ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt
sed -i '597 s/(\. [a-z])/\U&\E/' ~/UnixCourse/editingAss/mtswe10.txt
sed -i 's/you are conquered/ye are conquered/' ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt
sed -i 's/Elephant/Wombat/g' ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt
sed -i 's/elephant/wombat/g' ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt
```

You could do all of this in a pipeline without using `-i`:

```
cp ~cs252/Assignments/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst
sed '597 s/\([;]\)/./' ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt |
   sed -597 s/(\. [a-z])/\U&\E/' |
   sed 's/you are conquered/ye are conquered/' |
   sed 's/Elephant/Wombat/g' |
   sed 's/elephant/wombat/g' > tmp.txt
mv tmp.txt ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt
```

Comment: I get your point and thanks for showing me this. However  I am not sure what command to use for this : "  Save your changed file, and exit the editor. (Do not rename the file when you save it. It should still be named mtswe10.txt.) "

Comment: For some reason the part you suggested using wihtout -i did not work, but the first one with less parameters worked until the last step. I get that you are moving the file to tmp.txt and that moves it to mtswe10.txt but the command gives me error.

Comment: Well, the "exit the editor" note sounds like they were expecting you to use `vi` or some interactive editor.  `sed` saves the file every time it runs.  What error do you get?

Comment: So I ran all the commands with sed -i and no errors. After I did the last step with elephant/wombat I ran the code  provided: ~cs252/bin/editingAsst and the error was :  It appears you did not change line 597.(Did you save your changes before exiting the editor?). Is there a specific sed -i command to save file without renaming it?

Comment: You need to be specific.  The so-called "error" you're quoting comes from your teacher's checker, right?  That means your sed commands for 597 are wrong.  You can't do those separate, you will have to do them as one command: find the semicolon, match the next char, and capitalize it.

Comment: Like  `'597s/;\(.\)/\U\1\E/`.

Comment: Yes, from teachers checker. After I combined them I still get the you did not change the line or did not save it error. Is there a specific command for saving and quitting or sed does it all? I believe he wants me to use nano, vim or emac but I do not know anything about them. Wondering if it is too hard to convert these commands to one of those(nano,emac or vim). By the way, thanks for your patience and help Tim! I appreciate it.

Comment: Have you looked at the file to see what it looks like?  Does 597 have a semicolon followed IMMEDIATELY by a letter, or is there a space in between?

Comment: So, you were allowed to use an interactive editor for this assignment?  Then why are you wasting time writing a script?  This assignment would take you 2 minutes, and then you'd be done.  vi supports most sed command right out of the box.

Comment: Yes we're allowed but I couldn't make them work, I tried vim and emac, kept getting errors at different points. If you don't mind sharing, could you please help me with that? By using one of the interactive editors. Because I had no luck. Thank you!

Comment: Well, the first one in vi would be "597G" to go to line 597, "f;" to find the semi-colon, "x" to remove it, then cursor over until you find a lower-case char, and "~" to upper-case it.  For the other commands, just type ':%' (colon percent, to apply to all lines) followed by your sed commands exactly as you have them.  Then "ZZ" to save and exit.

Comment: So it would be:.                                                               
 mkdir ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst
cp ~cs252/Assignments/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst
vi
597G and then f and then x and ~ and then sed commands? So I still need to use sed commands right? Sorry if it sounds like a silly question..

Comment: No, you wouldn't use a script at all.  You would type the commands in by hand, live and in person.  Type the `mkdir`, type the `cp`, then do `vi ~/UnixCourse/editingAsst/mtswe10.txt`.  That brings up the full-screen editor.  Have you never used `vi`?

Comment: Thanks for your help Tim ! Here is what I did, I started with mkdir and cp and then the vi code to start editing the text. I used ? man men to find it and i to replace it with many men and scrolled down to line 597 to find semicolon that insert and replace with period. also used ':%s/elephant/wombat/gc 'to replace it, then I saved the file and quit. It worked, thanks for your help through the process!